# JQuery fadeIn not fully fading in on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I've been dealing with a bug in Chrome when using fadeIn to display content. It will either show but be transparent, or blocks of it will appear at full opacity while other blocks do not appear at all. When the browser repaints it, i.e. by resizing the window, or highlighting the content, etc, the content displays correctly.

When tested in Safari and Firefox, it fades in correctly.

```
$(stuff).hide().appendTo("body").fadeIn(100);
```

Replicated here: http://jsfiddle.net/kuiche/x9fwdaLc/

Comment: 1. Never write html from javascript, avoid this as much as possible. 2. This is not a bug report website. 3. Fades correctly to me, must be from your browser/OS

Comment: The html is a response of an Ajax call in the actual application. The jsfiddle is a minimal example. Have you tried running it a few times? There is the occasional time it does work...

Comment: Can't reproduce on Chrome here. Am on Chrome v39 with hardware acceleration on, if that matters.

Comment: Can reproduce from time to time on Chrome Beta (v40), seems like a good old timing issue. If I up the duration to 130 (or higher), all renders well. If I put the fade line in a timeout 0 callback, all renders well. If I put the appendTo and fade part in the callback of hide, all renders well. Lots of workarounds available, it seems.

Comment: Ah, I noticed that adding a delay in made it work more often than not (not 100% though). The callback in hide seems to be working in jsFiddle and seems to be the best solution. Thanks!

Comment: it works but 100 is to fast just try $(stuff).hide().appendTo("body").fadeIn(3000);

Comment: Can reproduce on Chrome 41 on OS X Yosemite. I suspect it is due to a painting issue, where the frame rate of the browser is simply too slow to fully display the range of opacity the element is cycled through. Adding a delay seems to work, so as extending the transition time to 125ms and beyond.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(stuff).hide().appendTo("body").fadeIn(100, function() {
  $(this).show();
});
```

Force a full show on the element as a callback when it's completed it's fadeIn.